# Image Slider pause on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

i have simply code that i got from W3SChool about Animated Image Slider. but this slider can't stop or pause when mouse on hover. please help me what should i add to this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
<p>The w3-animate-fading class animates an element in and out (takes about
```

10 seconds).

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
setTimeout(carousel, 9000);    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not so easy.. The fading of the image is handled by a continuing animation, while the swapping takes place through the function once ever 10s. You can check for the `:hover` pseudo class, but you have to do this at both animation and function level.

Comment: can it be done easier with a click or a stop button, then?